# Import Error With Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-cache

My requirements.txt file does not seem to be working

One of the lines in my file states:

```
Flask-Cache==0.12
```

However, I am getting the following error why I try to use Flask-Cache:

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.cache
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What Flask version do you use? [flask.ext.* redirect package prior to 0.8 is available only using the compatibility script](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#flask-before-0-8).

Try importing `flask_cache` instead of `flask.ext.cache`

Comment: I am using Flask version 0.9. So I guess I should be using flask_cache instead?